# SQL Join Returns null

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to return some values from database

**WHAT I HAVE**

USERS

user_id (pk)

[image]

OWN_EVENTS

user_id (fk)

event_id(pk)
[image]

ATTENDEES

user_id (fk)

event_id(fk)

[image]

**WHAT I NEED TO RETURN**

I need to return all the rows in `ATTENDEES` that's event_id equals to some value,status is not equal to 3 and , event_name value of that event from `OWN_EVENTS` table and email value  from `USERS` table

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
I have been trying all sort of combinations but couldnt figure out what I am doing wrong
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Even this returns null:

```
SELECT A1.event_name,A1.start_date  
FROM ATTENDEES A1  
INNER JOIN OWN_EVENTS A2  ON  A2.event_id = A1.event_id
WHERE A1.event_id = $event_id
```

or

```
SELECT A1.event_name,A1.start_date ,A3.email 
FROM ATTENDEES A1  
INNER JOIN OWN_EVENTS A2  ON  A2.event_id = A1.event_id
INNER JOIN USERS A3  ON  A3.user_id = A1.user_id
WHERE A1.event_id = $event_id AND A1.status != 3
```

What query call do I need to make?

EDIT:::::
Sample Data:

Attendees

[image]

OwnEvents

[image]

Users

[image]

Comment: Do you have more sample data? The `ATTENDEES` table has one row but the others have none. `INNER JOIN`s will therefore always return no rows.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski added some sample data screen shots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the join to the users table.  You are joining from `ATTENDEES`.  However, I think you want the owner email.

This switches the joins to `left outer join`.  This will return all matching rows in the `ATTENDEES` table, even when there are no matches in the other tables:

```
SELECT oe.event_name, a.start_date, u.email 
FROM ATTENDEES a left outer join 
     OWN_EVENTS oe
     ON oe.event_id = a.event_id left outer join
     USERS u
     on a.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE a.event_id = $event_id AND a.status <> 3
```

Comment: in phpmyadmin when I query for event id '148' for event_id I got `#1054 - Unknown column 'a.event_name' in 'field list'`

Comment: @MordFustang . . . That is fixed, but that was a problem in your sample query.  You took event name from the `ATTENDEES` table rather than `OWN_EVENTS`, where it should come from.  Uses table abbreviations for aliases really helps prevent such errors.

Comment: Yeah I have changed query to `oe.event_name, oe.start_date, u.email` and MySQL returned an empty result set. COuld you look at my sample data real quick, I have added some screen shpts from database

Comment: @MordFustang . . . You may have a type conflict on different columns.  I would suggest that you set up the example in SQL Fiddle (www.slqfiddle.com), with your table definitions and sample data.

Comment: Actually `oe.event_name, oe.start_date, u.email` is working I was keep copy pasting worng event id